# Постоянный перезапуск приложения через systemd

Tags: linux, systemd

Есть такая настройка сервиса systemd:

```
    [Unit]
    Description=wildfly
    After=network.target
    After=syslog.target

    [Install]
    WantedBy=multi-user.target

    [Service]
    Type=forking
    User=root
    Group=root
    ExecStart=путь до запуска
    WorkingDirectory=рабочая директория
    Restart=always
    RestartSec=20
    TimeoutSec=300
```

проблема в том, что мое приложение постоянное перезапускается.
С памятью на сервере все ок,
в логе приложения нашел такую строку:
`2018-08-27 00:03:43,084 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Thread-2) WFLYSRV0220: Server shutdown has been requested via an OS signal`
Грешу на эти настройки, с systemd на Вы.

Comment: А если его "с руки" запустить?

Comment: Все работает без проблем, запускал с консоли, пока консоль работает он работает. Посмотрел логи еще раз, убийство приложения происходит ровно через 5 минут как в свойстве TimeoutSec, убрал это свойство, вместо него поставил TimeoutStartSec, но чет все равно падает, попробую вообще это свойство убрать.

Comment: Убрал TimeoutStartSec, все равно падает...

Comment: типы служб: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd_(%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9)#.D0.A2.D0.B8.D0.BF.D1.8B_.D1.81.D0.BB.D1.83.D0.B6.D0.B1

Comment: @alexander barakin поставил тип simple и все заработало, спасибо, сделайте ответом, помечу как верный! Еще раз спасибо! Спасли!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> [Service]
> Type=forking
> ```

выбранный вами [*тип службы* подразумевает](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd_(%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9)#.D0.A2.D0.B8.D0.BF.D1.8B_.D1.81.D0.BB.D1.83.D0.B6.D0.B1), что процесс, запускаемый командой, описанной в `ExecStart`, порождает другой процесс(-ы) и завершает свою работу. если это так и есть, то надо в той же секции `[Service]` указать ещё и

```
PIDFile=/путь/к/файлу/содержащему/pid/порождённого/процесса
```

если же (скорее всего) запускаемый процесс остаётся работать и сам выполняет фукции сервиса, то надо изменить тип на `simple`:

```
Type=simple
```

или вообще удалить эту строку, т.к. тип `simple` подразумевается по умолчанию.

---

доп. чтение:

- [`man systemd.service`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html)